# How does getBoundingClientRect() interact with box-sizing?

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface

So jQuery's `.width()` [always returns the clientWidth](https://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/16/jquery-1-8-box-sizing-width-csswidth-and-outerwidth/), regardless of what it is. But if you want subpixel accuracy, [you have to opt for getBoundingClientRect](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=360889).

My question is a cross-browser question. Say I want to use getBoundingClientRects() or getBoundingClientRect(). In all major browsers used today (i.e. those used by at least 95% of people), do they return the width of the client area, i.e. essentially the `element.clientWidth` regardless of the box-sizing? Or do I have to subtract the padding if the element has `box-sizing: border-box` ? For that matter, how do I get subpixel values for padding and margins?

I am looking for an answer that speaks about the behavior of major browsers in use today.

Comment: It's more like `offsetWidth` (border is included whatever the box-sizing)

Comment: yes, I agree that `clientWidth` and `offsetWidth` are clear, but the question is about how `getBoundingClientRect` behaves in various browsers

Comment: I'm not saying it's more clear, Bounding client rect is clear for me. I am saying that gBCR().width will be almost the same as offsetWidth, for every browser following the specs, but with higher precision.

Comment: Aha got it. And you are sure this works for Ll browsers? So write an answer and I will mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 1):

From MDN : <sub>emphasize mine</sub>

> The returned value is a `DOMRect` object which is the union of the rectangles returned by `getClientRects()` for the element, **i.e., the CSS border-boxes** associated with the element.

So this method does return the border-boxes, and thus should not be influenced by the `box-sizing` attribute whatsoever.

So `width` and `height` values of the returned DOMRect will be the same as the ones returned by [`offsetWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth) and [`offsetHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight) properties, except that these later are rounded.

---

I can only say that this is what specs ask UAs to implement. I don't know how the different implementations did differ. IIRC, some early implementations of `getBoundingClientRect` did round `width` and `height` values too, but I have no idea of the browser usage of such buggy implementations.